# mySQL - Inserting data taking slow time

Tags: c#, mysql, performance

I have issue on the performance of my program using C#.

In first loop, the table will insert and update 175000 records with 54 secs.
In the second loop, with 175000 records, 1 min 11 secs.
Next, the third loop, with 18195 1 min 28 secs.
The loop going on and the time taken is more for 125 records can go up to 2 mins.

I am wondering why would smaller records taking longer time to update? Does the number of records updating does not give effect on the time taken to complete the loop?

Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Flow of Program:

Insert into TableA (date,time) select date,time from rawdatatbl where id>=startID && id<=maxID; //startID is the next ID of last records

update TableA set columnName = values, columnName1 =values, columnName2 = values, columnName.....

I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: Please show the code you are asking about.

Comment: are performing insert and updates in all the three loops?

Comment: @un-lucky yes, for this table A, each loops will insert date and time by selecting date and time from other tables say raw data table, then the program will update the values in the table A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reported behavior seems consistent with growing size of table, and inefficient query execution plan for `UPDATE` statements. Most likely explanation would be that the `UPDATE` is performing a full table scan to locate rows to be updated, because an appropriate index is not available. And as the table has more and more rows added, it takes longer and longer to perform the full table scan.

Quick recommendations:

review the query execution plan (obtained  by running EXPLAIN)

verify suitable indexes is available and are being used

Apart from that, there's tuning of the MySQL instance itself. But that's going to depend on which storage engine the tables are using, MyISAM, InnoDB, et al.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables, and the actual statements.  Here are some guesses...

- The target table has indexes.  Since the indexes are built as the inserts occur, any "random" indexes will become slower and slower.
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` was so small that caching became a problem.
- The `UPDATE` seems to be a full table update.  Well, the table is larger each time.
- How did you get `startID` from one query before doing the next one (which has `id>=startID`)?  Perhaps that code is slower as you get farther into the table.
- You say "in the second loop", where is the "loop"?  Or were you referring to the `INSERT...SELECT` as a "loop"?